# Can I get wxWidgets without Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am a c++ developer, and I really want to use wxWidgets, but I don't use Visual Studio.
I can't find any information on how to install wxWidgets without Visual Studio.
Is it even possible?

EDIT:
It is possible, close this question.

Comment: which compiler do you use? or you are going to cross-compile? If you use MinGW/gcc there is plenty of info and there is an official documentation on how to compile the library... so we need more info in order to help you.

Comment: ***Can I get wxWidgets without Visual Studio?*** Yes, its cross platform it works on a variety of operating systems and compilers. Your problem is you probably were looking for precompiled binaries on windows instead of building from source. Related: [https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW)

Comment: just so you know I use windows with mingw

Answer (score 2):

Installation instructions are in the file `docs/msw/install.md` and it describes building wxWidgets with gcc in [this section](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.4/docs/msw/install.md#cygwinmingw-compilation---------------msw_build_cygwin).

FWIW gcc is fully supported for building wxMSW, both natively and cross-compiling.

Comment: I just want to know, how much space does wxWidgets take up when fully compiled?

Comment: Depends on the build (static or shared), optimization/debug symbols presence and the compiler used. Typically it's of order of a few/several hundred megabytes.